# How to return a line with X from the first list, if X is in the second list?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have two lists. The first is with adjectives and the second is with sentences.
I need to return a sentence, if there is an adjective from our list and write the sentence in a dictionary with value = 'adj'. It'd return (['Have a good day'], 'adj').
Or at least if it could just return the sentence with a match adj.

sents_cleaned = ['have a good day', 'don't forget your yellow umbrella', 'bold seagull']
adjectives = ['good', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']

This is what I've tried so far. Didn't work as expected, sorry, I'm a noobie.

```
for sents in sents_cleaned:
    sents = sents.strip().split(" ")
    for words in sents:
        for adj in adjectives:
            if adj in sents:
                print(sents)
```

Output would be ['have a good day', 'adj'],
['don't forget your yellow umbrella', 'adj']

Comment: Could you also provide sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to store it in a dictionary called d, with sentences as keys and adjectives as values.

The following code assumes you want only 1 adjective from each sentence. If however, you require multiple adjectives, keeping a dictionary of string to list of strings would help.

```py
d = dict()
for sents in sents_cleaned:
    sents = sents.strip().split(" ")
    for word in sents:
        if word in adjectives:
            d[sents] = word
print(d)
```